# Handle in a console app

Tags: .net, winapi, gdi+

I have a console app in .net that I'm doing some processing of fonts. I'm using Win32APIs for this and one of them requires a device context for loading a font - actually a `IntPtr hdc = GetDC(handle of screen element)`. Obviously, my app doesn't have these handles as it's a console app. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: @TCLo - Which win32 API do you need to pass the handle to?  The MSDN documentation might give us more information as to which specific DC will work for you, so we can tell you how to grab it.

Answer (score 3):

In win32 GetDC( null ) should give a context back (for the entire screen)

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144871(VS.85).aspx)

So you should be able to do something like

```
IntPtr hdc = GetDC( null );
if( hdc == null ) 
{
    OopsError();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`GetConsoleWindow()` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683175.aspx):

> Retrieves the window handle used by the console associated with the calling process.

Alternatively, passing NULL might work. From the `GetDC()` docs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144871.aspx):

> A handle to the window whose DC is to be retrieved. If this value is NULL, GetDC retrieves the DC for the entire screen.

Answer (score 1):

`IntPtr hdc = GetDC(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle);` works in .Net console apps just fine.

I don't believe `null` will work in .Net as it kicks *Error, Argument: cannot convert from `'<null>'` to `'System.IntPtr'`*